# How to use don't mind + negative

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence, conditionals, negation

I am really confused about how to use don't mind in negative sentences. Which one is correct?

I can understand you, if you don't mind not speaking so fast.

I can understand you, if you don't mind speaking so fast.

I can understand you, if you mind not speaking so fast.

Comment: That's a tough one. There's no reason to use two negatives, though; it's confusing for the listener, too. Much better is _I can understand you if you don't mind speaking slower_. Even better is fronting the _if_-clause: _If you don't mind speaking slower, I can understand you._

Comment: "I can understand you, if you don't mind speaking slower."

Answer (score 1):

*If you don't mind* means—roughly—*if you will please* here. So only your first sentence is correct:

> *I can understand you, if you will please not speak so fast.*
>
> *I can understand you, if you don't mind not speaking so fast.*

It means the same as:

> *I can understand you, if you will please speak more slowly.*
>
> *I can understand you, if you don't mind speaking more slowly.*

Your second sentence, then, means the opposite, and *so* doesn't make sense:

> **I can understand you, if you will please speak so fast.* (incorrect)
>
> **I can understand you, if you don't mind speaking so fast.* (incorrect)

Your third sentence has an additional problem; it's missing the *do* auxiliary. We use *mind not* in questions, like this:

> *Do you mind not speaking so fast?* (*Will you please not speak so fast?*)
>
> *Do you mind speaking more slowly?* (*Will you please speak more slowly?*)

Answer (score 0):

If we take *mind* to have the definition of *being reluctant to do something*, then only your first sentence is correct. The second sentence below is assuming that being willing to do something is the opposite of being reluctant.

I can understand you, if you're not reluctant to not speak so fast.

= I can understand you, if you'll not speak so fast.

I can understand you, if you're not reluctant to speak so fast.

= I can understand you, if you'll speak so fast.

I can understand you, if you're reluctant to not speak so fast.

= I can understand you, if you won't not speak so fast.